# Share data between Elasticsearch data nodes on recipient request

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I have two Elasticsearch data nodes, Slave and Master.
M and S can communicate with each other, however for security reasons S cannot send data to M when it receives it, M must request data from S, and (assuming no other requirements on what data S exports) when this happens M receives the requested data from S.
S's data is then incorporated in to M's data.

Is this behaviour achievable with Elasticsearch? Unless I am mistaken, neither replication nor snapshotting achieve this behaviour, and while I am aware that I could use S's REST API to receive this data on M before purging copied data from S, this solution seems clunky and prone to error.
Is there an elegant solution to achieve this architecture?

Comment: I'm not sure I get it, but is this what you're looking for: https://www.elastic.co/blog/cross-datacenter-replication-with-elasticsearch-cross-cluster-replication ? (hint: cross-cluster replication)

Comment: I'm not sure, the read only property of this replication seems incompatible, M will need to continue to write it's own data in the meantime and S should not overwrite M either. Thank you anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is true that Cross Cluster Replication (CCR) is a potential solution for this, but that solution requires the most expensive version of elasticsearch, and there is a free alternative.

The elasticsearch [input](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-elasticsearch.html) and [output](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html) plugins for logstash work for this, albeit with some tweaking to get it to behave exactly as you want.
Below is a crude example which queries one elasticsearch node for data, and exports to another. This does mean that you require a logstash instance between the Slave and Master nodes to handle this behaviour.

```
input {
  elasticsearch {
    docinfo => true #Necessary to get metadata info
    hosts => "192.168.0.1" #Slave (Target) elasticsearch instance
    query => '{ "query": { "query_string": { "query": "*" } } }' #Query to return documents, this example returns all data which is bad if you combine with the below schedule
    schedule => "* * * * *" #Run periodically, this example runs every minute
  }
}
output { 
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => "192.168.0.2:9200" #Master (Destination) elasticsearch instance
    index => "replica.%{[@metadata][_index]}"
    document_id => "%{[metadata][_id]}"
  }
}
```